# Oracle PL/SQL split string into columns, convert to numbers, and insert into new table

Tags: sql, database, oracle

let's say I have this table, with a varchar column with the following values:

```
|   column1 |
|-----------|
|    (2, 7) |
| (2.24, 5) |
| (0, 43.5) |
```

I want to be able to get those values out of column1 and insert them into a table that has 
two number colums (converting the substrings to numbers); so far I've done the following:

```
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(PtsString.column1, '[^( ,]+', 1, 1) col_one,
       REGEXP_SUBSTR(PtsString.column1, '[^ )]+', 1, 2) col_two
FROM PuntosString;
```

It gives me this output:

```
| PT_ONE  | PT_TWO  |
|---------|---------|
|       2 |       7 |
|    2.24 |       5 |
|       0 |    43.5 |
```

I want to make a function that extracts those substrings from `pt_one` and `pt_two`, convert them to numbers and insert them into the table `NumPts (p1 number, p2 number)`;

What would you recommend me to solve this problem?

### Thanks!

**SOLVED**

So after hawk's recomendation, I did the following , being able to both convert the strings to numbers and insert them in NumPts table

```
INSERT INTO NumPts(p1,p2)
SELECT 
(TO_NUMBER(REGEXP_SUBSTR(PtsString.column1, '[^( ,]+', 1, 1))),
(TO_NUMBER(REGEXP_SUBSTR(PtsString.column1, '[^ )]+', 1, 2)))
FROM PtsString;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried TO_NUMBER function:

```
SELECT TO_NUMBER(REGEXP_SUBSTR(PtsString.column1, '[^( ,]+', 1, 1)) col_one,
       TO_NUMBER(REGEXP_SUBSTR(PtsString.column1, '[^ )]+', 1, 2)) col_two
FROM PuntosString;
```